# Continuous Function proof

Tags: calculus

Using the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity, show that the function $g(x) = |x|+1$, $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is continuous at any $c\in\mathbb{R}$.
Using the same definition, show that the function $h(x) = \lceil x\rceil - 2$ is discontinuous at any $c\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Here is a [tutorial for MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). From mobile, all I can see "box, box, box...". Please share your thought and/or work. ***Help us to help you.***

Comment: Done! What else?

Answer (score 0):

note that $\lceil z \rceil = z$ for $z\in\mathbb{Z}$ and for $0<\delta<1$ we have $$\lceil z+\delta \rceil = z+1\quad\text{and}\quad \lceil z-\delta \rceil = z$$
so let $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$ then no matter how small we choose $\delta>0$ we obtain
$$
z+1=\lceil z + \delta\rceil > \lceil z\rceil +\epsilon = z +\frac{1}{2}
$$
So $x\mapsto \lceil x\rceil$ cannot be continuous at $z\in\mathbb{Z}$.